# Home server software

Tags: windows, http

I have a computer that runs pretty much always. It runs windows 8.1 and due to being a gaming computer, is powerful enough to handle server operations. I would like to run a server software on it to host files of selected directories. It must have a web interface. Preferably must have a mobile website and be able to have multiple user accounts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/). It has a webinterface & mobile apps for android and iOS.

Comment: owncloud requires that i set up a server seperately, that requires technical knowledge, and though i have it, is not what i need.

Comment: still not what i needed, but selected it as question is closed.

Comment: what about using owncloud on a virtual machine on your computer?